Colors exploded switching from Wayland to X11
I was using Wayland for a long time. Switched to X11 now and colors have exploded. Too much saturation. How can I make it more natural colors? I can't see any color profile in settings.


Open Settings and navigate to the Color section.
Select your display and click Add profile.
Try using any of the existing color profiles, until you find one you are satisfied with.

Learn more about color management and how color profiles work from the official Ubuntu Documentation.

I found it after I asked the question but thanks anyway.

@AndrewHarlan Remember, if you have found a suitable solution to a question you have asked on AskUbuntu, you can always answer your own question and share your knowledge with the community: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

I had to leave only one color profile for each monitor (sRGB in both cases), otherwise I could not login, the system hanged. (Displays: primary 2560x1600, secondary 3840x2160)
